# When one of my Slack messages receives an emoji reaction, where can I see when the emoji reaction was sent?

Tags: slack, emoji

My Slack messages sometime receive emoji reactions. When one of my Slack messages receives an emoji reaction, where can I see when the emoji reaction was sent?

---

Example of emoji reaction:

[image]

Mouse over doesn't show any timestamps:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to see when the emoji reaction was sent when one of one's Slack messages receives an emoji reaction in the default Slack UI using only built-in Slack features.

However, as Reddit user [andrewfromx](https://www.reddit.com/user/andrewfromx) [told me](https://redd.it/14zuuy6), the Slack API does have the timestamp. From https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added:

```
{
    "type": "reaction_added",
    "user": "U123ABC456",
    "reaction": "thumbsup",
    "item_user": "U222222222",
    "item": {
        "type": "message",
        "channel": "C123ABC456",
        "ts": "1360782400.498405"
    },
    "event_ts": "1360782804.083113"
}
```

Reddit user [andrewfromx](https://www.reddit.com/user/andrewfromx) [pointed me](https://redd.it/14zuuy6) to some [application](https://many.pw/synapse/three) that displays the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Mentions & reactions` view definitely tabulates all the emoji reactions with responses looking like `UserX reacted to your message`. But the times showing up in that view don't appear to be the time of the emoji but rather the time of the message. Given your API finding it looks like there's a differentiation of `ts` vs `event_ts` so it appears the UI just ignores it with the current design.

```
Version 4.33.90
9ba5da5b777a51cabb2faf4adbeb66b748907398@1694578646 (Production)
```

[image: reactions view sample]